# list adapter shows null on debug android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview to populate some data from a static arraylist of class Common.the list adapter shows null on debugging.I am using ArrayAdapter and I saw a lot of solutions on stack but still the same issue.please help me

my code where I am calling the adapter

```
    displayListAdapter = new DisplayListAdapter(this);
    listView_contacts.setAdapter(displayListAdapter);
```

my adapter class

```
public class DisplayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
FragmentTransaction ft;
int clickedPosition;
String displayContacts,displayContactNumber;
private WebServiceCoordinator mWebServiceCoordinator;
TextView name_contactList;
Button call_contact;

public DisplayListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.contacts_list1_row);
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list1_row, parent, false);

    name_contactList = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contactlist_name);
    call_contact = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.contactlist_call);
    try {
        //if(Common.FLAG_contactsLoaded)
        //{
        displayContacts = Common.selectedContactName.get(position);
        displayContactNumber = Common.selectedContactNos.get(position);
        //}
            /*else {
                displayContacts = ((DisplayContacts) context).selectedContactName.get(position);
                displayContactNumber = ((DisplayContacts) context).selectedContactNos.get(position);
            }*/
        //String displayContacts = Common.selectedContactName.get(position);
        //String displayContactNumber = Common.selectedContactNos.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, "name to display" + displayContacts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "no.to display" + displayContactNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //name_contactList.setText(((DisplayContacts) context).selectedContactName.get(position));
        name_contactList.setText(displayContacts);
        //name_contactList.setText("dummy text");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("populating error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return rowView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add data to your adapter? I didn't see any code related to it.
You should write like:

```
displayListAdapter = new DisplayListAdapter(this);  
displayListAdapter.add("1");  
displayListAdapter.add("2");
```

or using

```
super(context, R.layout.contacts_list1_row, "your data list")
```

constructor instead of

```
super(context, R.layout.contacts_list1_row);
```

hope that may help :)

Comment: data is getting added using a Common Class in SplashActivity.u can see it in adapter Common.selectedContactNos.get(position);

Comment: @user8601021 I see that but it's not enough, you have to make the connection between data and adapter so that you must "add" or use the right constructer, otherwise the getView function will never be called since the adapter don't know the data count in the first place.

Comment: i have added a dummy arraylist in constructor and it works I am not getting the right position of contact name and corresponding fetched contact number from arraylist.so pls help me in adding two arraylists in constructor

Comment: @user8601021 the list that "store the contact name and numbers" is the exactly list you should add into the constructor, not other dummy arraylist bro. We use just one list to store data and make everything (id ,number, ect) in to a class object as an single list item. then we put this list to the constructor and the position will be fine. or you'll post all the Common class and I'll help you to fix?

Comment: @user8601021 or you just need to add the list which stored contact name will work, if you confirm that the size of  list of contact name and the size of the list of contact number is the same.

Comment: ok let me fetch it in 1 arraylist using getter and setter and try